# Execution halted when I use knitr and Rscript with opts_chunk

Tags: r, bash, knitr, rscript

I wrote a bash script in Mac OS that takes my .rnw file, knit it and then makes a .pdf. To knit my file, I'm using the command

```
Rscript -e "library(knitr); knit('file.rnw', encoding='utf8')"
```

and everything works fine. However, I don't want the ## characters in my final document. I tested, using R prompt, the following commands

```
library(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(comment=NA)
knit('file.rnw', encoding='utf8')
```

and they give me exactly what I want: the document without comments in the R commands output. But if I try to run

```
Rscript -e "library(knitr); opts_chunk$set(comment=NA); knit('livro.rnw', encoding='utf8')"
```

I get

```
Error: could not find function "opts_chunk"
Execution halted
```

as result. What am I doing wrong? How can I ask for options for my chunk in knitr using the command line?

Comment: [cross-posted in R-help](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2013-March/350285.html) and answered there; I hope someone can move the answer here.

Comment: You can instead put the following in your RMD file for example... `knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo=TRUE)` inside an `r chunk`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what Yihui meant when he said "move the answer here" but *here* is Duncan Murdoch's R-help answer that Yihui ratified:

> That looks like a bash problem:  it appears to be replacing $set with
>   a blank string.  Use appropriate quoting or escaping to tell it not to
>   do that.  (I think using single quotes around the command will work;
>   you'll need double quotes within it.)

---

And Yihui added:

> Yes I believe that was the problem. Same question asked here:
>   https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/162#issuecomment-9017997

Comment: I was just too lazy to copy and paste :)